# Aligning Images into Row within DIV

Tags: css

I have some ads I need displayed as rows of three within a div #ad-720.

I had it working then something changed and now they are all in a column. The footer is also cut off instead of being fullwidth. I've tried adding display: inline-block and a few other suggestions I've found here thru search but nothing is working.

I'd appreciate any guidance I can get. I'm mostly a graphics guy who gets asked to solve code problems here and there! ;)

http://www.cavallino.com/

Right now the CSS for the div is set to:

```
#ad-720 {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: dont put a link to your site , instead take relavent code and post that here, that can be HTML or CSS

Comment: Yes put the HTML and CSS part of your website where your problem occurs. People are giving up some of their time for you, they don't want to waste it.

Comment: Sorry, pretty new to this.

Comment: Your CSS looks fine. The main problem is the divs get **nested**, rather than the same level, so fix the markup first.

Comment: http://codepen.io/  
create a new pen describing your problem

Answer (score 0):

For starters the display setting for the  is set to block. Try setting it to inline. If that doesn't handle it, post the relevant HTML/CSS here and we will help you out.

Comment: You can also check out this fiddle, which is demonstrating a different concept but all the images are displayed next to eachother http://jsfiddle.net/cameck/u2byny4b/5/

Comment: Thanks! I changed the display to inline and they are still all vertical. Right bow I have : #ad-720 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

Comment: What about for those images?

Comment: Any html/css on them?

Comment: No css on the images. They are just straight banner images with links.   <div id="ad-720"><div style='text-align: center;'><a href="http://rmauctions.com/consign/?&utm_source=Cavallino300x250&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=silverFerrariLusso&utm_campaign=MO15" onClick=_gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'Click' "Rm-Sothebys', 1.00, true);">
<img src="http://www.cavallino.com/content/wp-content/uploads/Rm-Sothebys-300x250.jpg"</div></div> <!-- end #ad-720 -->

Comment: Try out the Css in that fiddle I provided, you'll have to do some math for the width but it should work. Grab those specific images like this #ad-720 img {}